# Interpretation of $\Omega_\pm(x^c)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

In an answer regarding the behaviour of two functions, I got the following:

"*As in the proof of Theorem 15.2 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I, this eventually yields that $$\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=\Omega_\pm(x^c)\quad\text{for any}\quad c<3/4$$*

I would like to check if I interpret correctly the meaning of $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=\Omega_\pm(x^c)$ for $c=1/2$. Can I interpret that $-\sqrt{x}\leq\pi(x)-\sigma(x)\leq\sqrt{x}$?

I understand that the meaning of $\Omega_\pm(x^c)$ is deeper, as additionally express that the value of $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)$ has infinitely many changes of sign, but I would like to check that $_\pm(x^c)$ work as upper and lower bound for this oscillation, and thus my interpretation is correct.

If that is not the intrepretation, I would appreciate your help for understanding it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276843/showing-that-qx-frac6x-pi2-omega-pmx1-4), and in a comment [Peter Humphries](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2689/peter-humphries) explains that "*$\Omega_\pm$ is standard notation in analytic number theory. $f(x)=\Omega_\pm{(g(x))}$ means that $\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0$, while $\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 0$*".

From this definition, I conclude that the answer to my question would be **NO**, as my statement $-\sqrt{x}\leq\pi(x)-\sigma(x)\leq\sqrt{x}$ is stronger than $\pi(x)-\sigma(x)=\Omega_\pm(\sqrt{x})$.